# Solve for $x$: $\sqrt{12} - \sqrt[3\leftroot1]{720} = \sqrt{x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I want to solve for $x$

Here's the question

> $$\large \sqrt{12} - \sqrt[3\leftroot1]{720} = \sqrt{x}$$

I need to find the value of $x$

Help!

Comment: Hint: how can you get rid of the square root from $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: yeh i thought of making the base equal

Comment: making the base equal and solving gets long & probamatic

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{12}-\sqrt[3]{720}\approx-5.5<0$. While this suggests $x\approx(-5.5)^2\approx30.2$, by definition the square root of a positive real is positive. Hence there is no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you gave is 
$$
\sqrt{12}-\sqrt[3]{720}=\sqrt{x}
$$
The left side of this equation is less than $0$. The positive root of $x$ can never be less than $0$, so there's no solution.

Comment: so there's no need for actually solving this

Comment: on solving the left hand side i got 8.96 ~ is int like the answer be 3

Comment: one more thing since i expected this question to be solved in a minute or so how can i do for other questions like these the thing is that it is easy to calculate using calculator